# TypeError: list indices must be integers, not unicode

Tags: python, csv, unicode

I have a utf-8 encoded csv file and would like to use csv.DictReader instead of using csv.Reader in the class UnicodeReader in link - https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

```
class UTF8Recoder:  
    def __init__(self, f, encoding):  
        self.reader = codecs.getreader(encoding)(f)  
    def __iter__(self):  
        return self  
    def next(self):  
        return self.reader.next().encode("utf-8")  

class UnicodeReader:  
    def __init__(self, f, encoding="utf-8"):  
        f = UTF8Recoder(f, encoding)  
        self.reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=b',')  
    def next(self):  
        row = self.reader.next()  
        return [unicode(s, "utf-8") for s in row]  
    def __iter__(self):  
        return self  

def csv_dict_reader(file_obj):  
    reader = UnicodeReader(file_obj)  
    for line in reader:  
        val = line [“first_column”]  

if __name__ == "__main__":  
    try:  
        with open(“abcd.csv") as f_obj:  
         csv_dict_reader(f_obj)  
    except IOError:  
        print "Error: can\'t find file - tz_2k3.csv or read data"  
        raise SystemExit
```

I get error "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not unicode"

Comment: yes, just print `line` in for loop and also print type of line i.e. `type(line)`.

Comment: Why not use the `DictReader()` instead of creating a *new* reader here? You now get *lists*, not dictionaries.

Comment: In other words: why did you create two different readers?

Comment: Also, what is `file_obj` here? Can you give us a *minimal, complete sample of your code* that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 0):

**What is TypeError?**

**Exception TypeError**:
Raised when an operation or function is applied to an object of inappropriate type. The associated value is a string giving details about the type mismatch. [Just click on me for more information.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.TypeError)

**Demo:**

```
>>> l1 = ["value1", "value2", "value3"]
>>> type(l1) 
<type 'list'>
>>> l1[2]   # Need index to access item from the list.
'value3'
>>> l1["value1"]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

My colleague fixed this issue by modifying next method in class UnicodeReader, there was some issue due to UTF-8 BOM character

```
def next(self):  
    d = self.reader.next()  
    return {unicode(k, "utf-8").strip(u'\ufeff'): unicode(v, "utf-8").strip(u'\ufeff') for k, v in d.items()}
```

Comment: You can fix it without all the extra stripping by opening the file in `UnicodeReader` with the `utf-8-sig` codec instead.  It recognizes and removes `\ufeff` if present.  Example: `def __init__(self, f, encoding="utf-8-sig"):`.

Comment: @MarkTolonen : I fixed extra stripping based on your suggestion. Thank you.